# Cast column to integer with ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr

I use ogr2ogr to import an .sqlite file into my PostgreSQL database. The new database table I get has a column of type "character varying". However I want it be of type integer as all the values in the particular column are integer numbers with the exception of some empty fields. How do I do this?

Comment: Is that field reported as string or integer by ogrinfo `ogrinfo -al -so my_db.sqlite`?

Comment: @user30184 It is reported as string. `String (0.0)` to be more precise.

Comment: What is your GDAL version?

Comment: @user30184 `gdal-config --version` gives `2.2.2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it in the ogr2ogr `-sql` parameter then you want to use the `cast(<expr> AS <type-name>)` syntax - outlined in the 'CAST expressions' section [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

eg:
`SELECT cast(a.my_text_field AS int), a.geometry FROM mytable a` etc

If you want to do it in Postgres then you can use the same syntax or the `::` syntax.

If this isn't working post an example of your data and the code you've been trying.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this casting to work (I'm using the OCI driver to pull from an Oracle data source and write to a .csv), but used a workaround: a CASE statement

The problem is that the data I'm pulling from contain many nulls in these fields, and in some cases, one of the fields is 100% nulls.

*Ex.1
Tried to cast, but it didn't work when writing to CSV. I think this is the limitation of a CSV file itself (I don't think it can store field types at all).*

`select  CAST(s.slope AS int) as IAPP_slope, CAST(s.aspect AS int) as IAPP_aspect, CAST(s.elevation AS int) as IAPP_elev, from  invasive_plant_site s`

*Ex. 2 So instead, I use case statements to just write dummy int values as outputs when I encounter a null value, to ensure I have a clear-cut integer value in that field. I use 9999 as it's not an actual value I would encounter for any of these fields:*

`select case when s.slope is null then 9999 else s.slope end as IAPP_slope, -- force int field types via dummy value 9999 case when s.aspect is null then 9999 else s.aspect end as IAPP_aspect, case when s.elevation is null then 9999 else s.slope end as IAPP_elev, from  invasive_plant_site s`